# How to deal with errors gracefully in map method of Option?

Tags: rust

In the [Rust By Example book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/iter_result.html#fail-the-entire-operation-with-collect) show us a way to handle errors in the map method of Iterator:

```rust
    let strings = vec!["93", "tofu", "18"];
    let numbers: Result<Vec<_>, _> = strings.into_iter().map(|s| s.parse::<i32>()).collect();
    println!("Results: {:?}", numbers);
```

Is it a similar way to deal with errors in `Option` like the following?

```rust
    let a: Option<&str> = Some("tofu");
    let b: Result<Option<i32>, _> = a.map(|a| a.parse::<i32>());
    println!("Results: {:?}", b);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a handy method called [`.transpose()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.transpose) that can convert an `Option<Result<T, E>>` into a `Result<Option<T>, E>` (or the [reverse](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.transpose)):

```
let a: Option<&str> = Some("tofu");
let b: Result<Option<i32>, _> = a.map(|a| a.parse::<i32>()).transpose();
println!("Results: {:?}", b);
```